# Asus zenbook UX301L not warning about battery running out

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery, asus-laptop

For some reason, I no longer get the blue win8 warning message that used to say that my battery was running out. Instead of warning now my computer just suddenly turns off itself and if you didn't look at the meter for the battery then you could lose work when this happens. Is it some setting somewhere that I switched and must get set?

Comment: Its in Control Panel>power options>change plan settings>change advanced advanced settings>low battery notification. Your power plan should be set to "Balanced", if not change that first then drill down and check the advanced settings for the battery.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. My setting was "Power4Gear Performance" so I changed it to "Balanced" and now we'll see if it warns when batteries are running out.

Comment: You can use performance but you have to change the battery warning settings

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm: I also suggest that you search for tutorials online about recalibrating the battery and perform the procedure.